# How to add missing tag to a Stack Exchange question

Tags: support, edits, edit-summary

I saw a question on Stack Overflow and it's about Java. The post had a number of tags but not the important one, so the source code of that question looks as ugly as plaintext because the syntax highlighting was not working.

I tried to add `java` to the tags of that question, but I got an error

```
Your edit summary must be at least 10 characters
```

Can't we add missed tags for a question without adding anything to the body?

Comment: your edit SUMMARY - the explanation of what you did. Fill in that box saying "added Java tag" and you're all set

Comment: The error tells you that you need to fill in a *edit summary*, which is a separate field that tells people *why or what* you edited.

Comment: i was post wrong error .error is "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Comment: If you have a new question, please [ask a new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of radically changing this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill in the *editing summary*, the text box *after* the tags, to summarize what edits you made:

> [image: edit summary location]

When I edited your question, I edited the summary too. For 2k+ users, the edit summary is auto-generated if left blank, but when *suggesting* an edit, you need get to leave something for the reviewers to read.

Comment: i was post wrong error .error is "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"